# Select vertices within a given object

Tags: python, scripting, selection-tools

I am sculpting voxel-type meshes. I have a few methods for this and was working on a tutorial. Had an idea to use objects as a boolean type tool. Very close (I think) to a script but I am stumped. The following script is based on [this post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1zrp.png). It seems to only get vertices based on 'distance=' in this line.

```
result, point, normal, face = obj.closest_point_on_mesh(p, distance=.25)
```

It won't run if the Sphere is absent, but the Sphere doesn't seem to affect the selection in any way.

Script:

```
import bpy, bmesh

def is_inside(p, max_dist, obj):
    max_dist = 1.84467e+19
    result, point, normal, face = obj.closest_point_on_mesh(p, distance=.25)
    p2 = point-p
    v = p2.dot(normal)
    return not(v < 0.0)

obj = bpy.context.active_object
Sphere = bpy.data.objects['Sphere']
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action="DESELECT")

mesh=bmesh.from_edit_mesh(bpy.context.object.data)
for v in mesh.verts:
    p = obj.matrix_world @ v.co
    if is_inside(p,1,Sphere): v.select = True

print("script complete")
```

[image: carve out these cubes]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried applying its transform/scale/rotation by using ctrl-a?

Answer (score 1):

I think the missing piece you needed is this phrase from the `closest_point_on_mesh` function description, from [the docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=closest_point_on_mesh#bpy.types.Object.closest_point_on_mesh):

> Find the nearest point on evaluated geometry, **in object space**

So you need to translate the cube's vertex to world space, then translate it into the sphere's local space. Here's the revised script, adding the matrix transform plus a check when `result` returns false:

```py
import bpy, bmesh

def is_inside(p, max_dist, obj):
    result, point, normal, face = obj.closest_point_on_mesh(p, distance=max_dist) # you weren't using max_dist in yours, is that intentional?
    if not result:
        return False
    p2 = point-p
    v = p2.dot(normal)
    return not(v < 0.0)

obj = bpy.context.active_object
Sphere = bpy.data.objects['Sphere']
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action="DESELECT")

mesh=bmesh.from_edit_mesh(bpy.context.object.data)
sphere_matrix = Sphere.matrix_world.inverted()
mat = sphere_matrix @ obj.matrix_world # precalculating it here, to improve performance
for v in mesh.verts:
    p = mat @ v.co
    if is_inside(p,2,Sphere): v.select = True
    
    
# here's generator way to do the loop too
#selected_verts = [v
#    for v in mesh.verts
#    if is_inside((mat @ v.co), 2, Sphere)]
#for v in selected_verts:
#    v.select = True
```