# Parenting two cloth meshes in one cloth simulation doesn't work

Tags: modeling, cloth-simulation

i am trying to animate this bag. so first i shrinkwarped the handles to the bag, applied the modifier and joined the handles with the bag afterwards followed by merging the object by distance. if i try to simulate the bag as a cloth falling down to the floor the handles dont stay in place. when i apply a vertex group to the lower part of the handles and put it as a pin group in the shape section the bag doesnt fall at all...

i also tried to seperate the handles from the bag and parented them to the bag but its causing the same issues. Als tried it by exporting the handles as an alembic and shrinkwarp them afterwards, but this workaround is shitty since i have to animate the bag in different situations as a complete model, also there is stretching going on which looks shitty. I would be happy about any tip or tut, thank you in advance! Have a good weekend! PS i know marvelous designer would be better to use, but i have no license.

[image]

the straps should follow the creases of the bag which doestn work to attach properly, in the gif i animated the movement of the handles to fit the movement of the bag...

[image]

Comment: can u show us a video/animation (just add a link to your question) how it should look like? i mean the animation? thx.

Comment: Cloth sim is sensitive's at topology ... all you described (I expect) results in a very messy topology. So start model in nicer way or create a simpler version of bag (like Chris), bake simulation and use in Mesh deform modifier as proxy (target) for hires model.

Comment: Pin is not going to help you here, you'll need to figure a way to *sew* the non-manifold vertices of the strap to nearby vertices on the bag.  This I attempt in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I just "modelled" (sorry, i might be the worst modeller at all) a bag (in one part) and i got this:

[image]

If you are a perfectionist, that's not good - i know. But i think it's a good starting point.

The geometry looks like this:

[image]

Cloth settings are all default, except i tweaked the handle on the right side: i made a vertex group for just the vertices in the handle and gave them a value of 1.

I named my vertex group "stiffer" and used them as bending group with these values in the cloth settings:

[image]

So on the left side is all default, on the right side the bag has the "stiffer" handles.

Answer (score 0):

If your Merge had been successful, then you should be able to "Select >> By Trait >> Non Manifold" and no longer see many edges where the strap merged with the bag.   My guess is that this didn't end up doing what you expected:

[image]

Your shink-wrap will get vertices as close as possible, and your Join consolidates this into the same mesh.  So that's good.

If your Merge is failing to connect the who with new edges,  what you need is "Vertex >> (F) New Vertex/Edge from from Vertices", and you could then also enable *Sew* in the Cloth physics if only edges are created.
[image]

How to get there without tediously selecting pairs of strap and bag vertices, is a question that has been answered elsewhere (we can search this site).

[image]

In my example (attached) I chose a few pairs to create new edges (f) to sew. I can think of how I'd use python programming to step through non-Manifold edges of the strap section and create a new edge to the closest vertex on the bag section (something using code from [enter link description here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/177559/111042))

[image]